# Keep cursor placement after writing buffer to disk using external command

Tags: vim

I use a small snippet of vimscript code in my vimrc to be able to automatically encrypt the text to disk when executing `:write`. Unfortunately, every time I save the file, my cursor is reset to the start of the first line, forcing me to scroll down to where I was. Quite annoying.

Is there a way of restore the cursor placement after I have written the file to disk? The full code can be found below.

```
# code from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Encryption#ccrypt
augroup CPT
  au!
  au BufReadPre *.cpt set bin
  au BufReadPre *.cpt set viminfo=
  au BufReadPre *.cpt set noswapfile
  au BufReadPost *.cpt let $vimpass = inputsecret("Password: ")
  au BufReadPost *.cpt silent '[,']!ccrypt -cb -E vimpass
  au BufReadPost *.cpt set nobin
  au BufWritePre *.cpt set bin
  au BufWritePre *.cpt '[,']!ccrypt -e -E vimpass
  au BufWritePost *.cpt u
  au BufWritePost *.cpt set nobin
augroup END
```

Comment: Create a mark at the beginning of the augroup, and move to that mark at the end?
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks
Example:
See bulletlist:
 http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/30.html

Comment: You are looking for `winsaveview()`/`winrestview()`. It would be best to bundle your commands up into a function(s) to take advantage of these commands. However I worry that their will be some leaking with this method such as an unencrypted undo file. See `:h encryption`. Is using Vim's native encryption out of the question?

Comment: if you bundled your comments up in an answer, it would make it possible to upvote them :)

Comment: @Duikboot not sure where to put those marks, as I honestly don't read vimscript at all. to me, it looks like these are settings that are triggered onWrite, onRead, etc for that particular file type. to be able to put in marks, I would need to bundle up the commands in functions, right?

Comment: @PeterRincker found this one guy that has bundled the functions: https://github.com/atweiden/dotfiles/blob/master/_vim/functions/ccrypt.vim I guess I could work with that quite easily, but your tip on built-in encryption is tons better. don't know why I never found that out when googling for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be use Vim's built in encryption. Use `:X` to set the key. You can at this point use read and write the file the same as you normally would. See `:h encryption` for more details.

To answer you question on how to save and restore the cursor position:

- Use `winsaveview()` to save the view information. e.g. `let view = winsaveview()`
- Move the cursor
- Restore the view state. e.g. `call winrestview(view)`

As you noted you found [someone who bundled up](https://github.com/atweiden/dotfiles/blob/master/_vim/functions/ccrypt.vim) the autocmd's into some functions. You can probably modify this to use the `winsaveview()`/`winrestview()` function by saving the view state into a buffer variable. e.g. `let b:view = winsaveview()` and `call winrestview(b:view)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another version provided by **atweiden** includes simply storing and restoring the cursor before and after writes.

Code from [Github](https://github.com/atweiden/dotfiles/commit/1871ab2a0f49fbe58374bc5a9a4882e444c7fb8b):

```
  func! s:ccrypt_bufwritepre()
        let b:save_cursor = getpos(".")
        setl bin
        %!ccrypt -e -E crypticnonsense
    endfunc

    func! s:ccrypt_bufwritepost()
        u
        setl nobin
        call setpos('.', b:save_cursor)
    endfunc
```